# Jenkins auto deploying failed, when all settings are right. -- error in mapperLocations, Spring (illegalArgumentException, TomcatManagerException)

Tags: maven, jenkins, illegalargumentexception, autodeploy, tomcat-manager

I want to share some Jenkins auto-deployment issue solutions, that I could not find on the internet including here.
But I'm almost a freshman in StackOverflow, so I'm just here to ask myself and answer myself right away.
// I have tried to share the solution public on GitHub issue, I could not use it well, too.
// asking to be excused...

---

I'm using Spring MVC 4.3.9, connected to CI/CD.
// GitHub branch -> Jenkins -> TestServer (Tomcat 8.5)

I allowed all the IP addresses, made and set the right Tomcat Manager account both in Jenkins credentials menu and tomcat.
But the same error always occurs -- TomcatManagerException and also the illegal argument exception (in the full log from Jenkins by maven build option, -X -e, not sure). 
// Same results, with both Deploy war plugin and SSH_publish plugin.

Here is the Jenkins console output. (I don't think this one is the full log.)

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  7.895 s
[INFO] Finished at: ~~~Time~~~
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[DeployPublisher][INFO] Attempting to deploy 1 war file(s)
[DeployPublisher][INFO] Deploying ~~YourDIR&WAR~~ to container Tomcat 8.x Remote with context ~~YourContextName~~
  Redeploying [ ~~YourDIR&WAR~~]
  Undeploying  ~~YourDIR&WAR~~]
  Deploying [ ~~YourDIR&WAR~~]
ERROR: Build step failed with exception
org.codehaus.cargo.container.ContainerException: Failed to deploy [ ~~YourDIR&WAR~~]
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.deploy(AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.java:104)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.redeploy(AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.java:180)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.deploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:81)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$DeployCallable.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:167)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$DeployCallable.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:136)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1075)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1058)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.redeployFile(CargoContainerAdapter.java:133)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.PasswordProtectedAdapterCargo.redeployFile(PasswordProtectedAdapterCargo.java:95)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.DeployPublisher.perform(DeployPublisher.java:113)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.perform(BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.java:78)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$3.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:45)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:741)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:690)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:186)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:635)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1905)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:428)
Caused by: org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManagerException: The Tomcat Manager responded "FAIL - Deployed application at context path [~~YourContextName~~] but context failed to start
" instead of the expected "OK" message
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.invoke(TomcatManager.java:721)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.deployImpl(TomcatManager.java:767)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.deploy(TomcatManager.java:312)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.deploy(AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.java:99)
    ... 19 more
org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManagerException: The Tomcat Manager responded "FAIL - Deployed application at context path [~~YourContextName~~] but context failed to start
" instead of the expected "OK" message
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.invoke(TomcatManager.java:721)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.deployImpl(TomcatManager.java:767)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.deploy(TomcatManager.java:312)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.deploy(AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.java:99)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.redeploy(AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.java:180)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.deploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:81)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$DeployCallable.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:167)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$DeployCallable.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:136)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1075)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1058)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.redeployFile(CargoContainerAdapter.java:133)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.PasswordProtectedAdapterCargo.redeployFile(PasswordProtectedAdapterCargo.java:95)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.DeployPublisher.perform(DeployPublisher.java:113)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.perform(BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.java:78)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$3.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:45)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:741)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:690)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:186)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:635)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1905)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:428)
Build step 'Deploy war/ear to a container' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

* I also got illegal argument exception in maven console, in mapperLocations setting.
===> This is the key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://yourDBurl:yourport/yourDBname" />
        <property name="username" value="youraccountname" />
        <property name="password" value="youraccountpassword" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="mapperLocations" value="classpath:my/package/mapper/*.xml" />
    </bean>
<!--
// This is a part of the root-context.xml
// in `src/main/java/my/package/mapper`, there are XML mapper files. // "src/main/java"
// -- In my case, the mappers were in the classpath `src/main/java`
-->
```

This was my original mapper setting (causing the error). This setting just worked all fine when I run the Spring project on the local server. Also in the case that I exported war file on eclipse then deploy the war with my own hand to the server manually. Also in the case that I exported war file on eclipse then deploy the war with Tomcat Manager to the server manually.

** But only not available on Jenkins. Maven build was always successful but only in deployment. **


*** Solution ***
=> I have changed the mapper setting in the Spring project, and migrated mappers from `src/main/java` to `src/main/resources`
=> The cause of the error I have guessed is that Jenkins cannot read, `<property name="mapperLocations" value="classpath:my/package/mapper/*.xml" />`, this configuration.
=> Same JDBC config, I only changed the mybatis setting like this.

```
<!-- with same jdbc config -->
   <bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
      <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
      <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:mybatis/mybatis-configuration.xml" />
   </bean>
<!--
// This is a part of the root-context.xml
// NOW in `src/main/resources/my/package/mapper`, there are XML mapper files. // "src/main/resources"
-->
```

=> In  `src/main/resources/mybatis-configuration.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE configuration PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Config 3.0//EN" "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-config.dtd">
<configuration>
    <typeAliases>
        <!-- <typeAlias alias="yourDTO" type="my.package.dto.yourDTO"></typeAlias> -->
    </typeAliases>
    <mappers>
        <mapper resource="mybatis/mapper/yourmapper.xml" />
        <!-- mappers, and so on -->
    </mappers>
</configuration>
```

=> Put the mybatis mappers in the directory, `src/main/resources/mapper`. Write `yourmapper.xml` like usual mybatis mapper XML file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE mapper
  PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN"
  "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">
<mapper namespace="my.package.dto.yourDTO">
    <!-- your mybatis tag with SQL query -->
</mapper>
```

P.S.
-- I just have guessed that Jenkins cannot read the mappers in `src/main/java`.
-- I haven't actually understood or analyze the open-source code of Jenkins.
-- So the cause I pointed out might be wrong, but at least, the auto-deployment with Jenkins was available, in my mysterious case.
-- I hope this might be helpful.